# Db migration Onprem oracle to GCS

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, database-migration, batch-processing

In our application Documents stored in clob format in oracle in Onprem db
Looking for a tool/process/procedure to read and move the document from oracle to GCS (google cloud storage ) The total data volume is 30TB.
Thanks in advance!

Tools recommendations or procedures

Comment: I think, nothing exist.You have to write it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For 30 TB, the only solution I recommend is a Transfer Device: https://cloud.google.com/transfer-appliance/docs/4.0/overview

Comment: Can gcp batch help to extract clob and save it to GCS

Comment: It does not matter which service you use, you do not want to try and transfer 30 TB via the Internet. Almost all vendors charge for egress data transfer. Then there is the time required which would take a month. Do your research and then post a question.